# Display multiple images from indexeddb with angular

Tags: angular, typescript, indexeddb

I want to build an application with Angular.
I want to store objects in Indexeddb. These objects include images.
I managed to store the objects in Indexeddb.
The images are stored as blobs.
I can load the images from Indexeddb, but I can't display them.
All the examples I found are about 1 image and then you can do as described in:
https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/storing-images-and-files-in-indexeddb/
The way they do it there is not usable for multiple images.

Comment: are you loading image url or blob using indexdb

Comment: I store them as blobs

Answer (score 0):

You can store image as base64String in indexedDb.

```
var image={"Base64String":"","name":"file1.jpg"};
indexedDbService.post("tablename", image);
```

And you can view the image as base64string as source for image tag like below.

```html
 <img style='display:block; width:100px;height:100px;' id='base64image'                 
       src='data:image/jpeg;base64, LzlqLzRBQ...<!-- base64 data -->' />
```